# Gremlin shell with MongoDB error

Tags: mongodb, groovy, gremlin

To get started, I downloaded the *GMongo* and *Mongo Java Driver* jar files and I put them inside C:\gremlin-groovy-2.6.0\lib.
Then I wrote the following codes in Gremlin shell:

```
gremlin> import com.gmongo.GMongo
gremlin> mongo = new GMongo()
```

The second line failed with this message:

```
gremlin>  mongo = new GMongo()
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/gremlin-groovy-2.6.0/lib/logback-classic-0.9.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/gremlin-groovy-2.6.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
22:03:28.590 [main] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=50}
22:03:28.652 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
==>com.gmongo.GMongo@5286c33a
gremlin> 22:03:29.684 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5570af10acc16d0aec05e40e', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
22:03:29.699 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5570af10acc16d0aec05e40e', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: You can get rid of the slf4j warning by removing one of those two jars (i'd delete `logback-classic-0.9.30.jar`).  Is mongodb running on `localhost`?

Comment: Yes it'running on localhost.

Comment: well - the `MongoSocketException` is a pretty good clue that you have some form of network related problem and you're clearly getting a refused connection.  I'm not sure what that would be though just off the top of my head.

Comment: I deleted logback-classic-0.9.30.jar and it works. Thank you

Comment: Maybe delete this question?